# Emoji not found error whe adding reaction in discord.py

Tags: python, emoji, discord.py

I want my bot to react to the author's message with a emoji specified by the user - however, I get the error "emoji not found"

I've searched all over SO, but I can only find stuff for custom emotes. I don't know why it gives out this error, so I couldnt do much..

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def react(ctx, emoji:discord.Emoji):
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Expected result is to add a reaction to the user's message

Actual result is this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Emoji "ð" not found.
```

(when executing command *react :thumbs_up:)
(Prefix for my bot is "*")

Answer (score -1):

A [`PartialEmoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PartialEmoji)object can represent either a custom emoji or a unicode emoji:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def react(ctx, emoji:discord.PartialEmoji):
    if emoji.is_custom_emoji():
        processed_emoji = bot.get_emoji(emoji.id)
    else:
        processed_emoji = emoji.name;
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(processed_emoji)
```

Comment: says coulsnt convert to partial emoji now

Comment: Ok so there were lots of errors in this message and uh its still not wotkin (like is_custom_emoji doesnt exist, you mistaled bot for client etc)

Comment: Are you using the latest version?  Check `print(discord.__version__)`